# Python - How to extract content inside XML tag and get tag position?

Tags: python

for example i have sentence:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

i give tags for subject and object:

```
<subject>The quick brown fox</subject> jumps over <object>the lazy dog</object>
```

i want a function to return a dictionary

```
{'subject':[0,18] #0 is index of letter "T" and 18 is index of letter x from 'The quick brown fox'
 'object':[30, 42] #30 is index of letter "t" and 42 is index of letter g from 'the lazy dog'
}
```

How to do that ?

Comment: do you know about beautifulsoup?? If not then check it out, I guess it will help you a lot. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether the result is right or not. Post it for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

def getLocation(ele, html, offset):
    length = html.index('>', ele._start) - html.index('<', ele._start) + 1 # Start tag length
    start = ele._start - offset
    end = html.rindex('<', 0, ele._end) - length - 1 - offset
    length2 = ele._end - html.rindex('<', 0, ele._end) # End tag length
    offset = offset + length + length2 # Total tag length
    return [start, end], offset

html = '''<subject>The quick brown fox</subject> jumps over <object>the lazy dog</object>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
subject = doc.subject
obj = doc.object
locSub, offset = getLocation(subject, html, 0) # First element
locObj, offset = getLocation(obj, html, offset)
dic = {'subject': locSub, 'object': locObj}
print(dic)
```

Result:

```
{'subject': [0, 18], 'object': [31, 42]}
```